# perl5 Number Sign # not working for comments

Tags: linux, apache, comments, perl, embperl

I have a very strange problem..

perl5 Number Sign # not working correctly for comments..

We use emperl, mod_perl, apache, linux..

In some programs if I have a line commented out with a number sign # or just a number sign # by itself on a line, all of the code below that line doesn't work correctly.

There is a sysadmin so I don't have access or control over any of the settings on the server.

This is a new issue everything always worked previously.

So many possible area's that this might be coming from that I'm checking to see if anybody has run across this..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, all things being equal, "#" should very definitely work as a Perl comment.  The problem is "something else".  SUGGESTIONS: Q: "What changed" since the script last worked?  Q: Can you post a snippet before and after one of the "failing comments"?

Comment: An additional means to checking what might be happening would be to use **hd** or **od** against the file, and examine the # character itself, and whatever follows it.

Comment: I don't know what happened.  I've check rights and permission on the directory and files.  Tried renaming the file.  IF I create a new blank file, copy all of the logic over to the new file, delete the old file and rename the new file to the old name, the number sign # for comments work again! Strange, very strange.  BUT it works!

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:

Was transferring the files from LINUX to Windows to edit them.

If the file was originally created in Windows the end of a line was just a <CR> and for some reason the whole file wasn't running right.  It mainly showed up when using the hash symbol for perl comments.

When I made sure the files had end of lines with <CR><LF>, this solved this issue.